# Is there any way to send request via authenticated proxy in OpenBSD netcat (nc)?

Tags: proxy, nc

I am using following command using the nc to connect to my server via proxy (localhost:8080). But this proxy is authenticated. I am not sure how to pass the auth details. Pls. note **this is older version of "nc" which doesn't have -P proxy_username as option**

```
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port] [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version] [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]

"ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x localhost:8080 %h %p"
```

Note- I want this using OpenBSD nc only not via ncat or the nc of nmap-ncat